# How to determine all possible convergence ranges of laurent serie for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-1}, z_0=3+2i$

My idea:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-1}=\frac{1}{4(z-1)}-\frac{1}{4(z+1)}-\frac{2}{4(z^2+1)}=-\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } z^n - \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } (-z)^n-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } (-z^2)^n  $

But I am not sure how to get all convergence ranges from it?

Comment: If you're expanding around $z=0$, each of the series your wrote converge for $|z|<1$.  You still need $|z|>1$.

Comment: Where did you use the fact that $z_0=3+2i$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didnt.